# Redshift can't drop table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am running on redshift this command:

```
DROP TABLE schema.table cascade;
```

It runs forever and says:

```
[57P01] FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
```

I terminate the pid with this command:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(1085766906)
```

Try to drop the table again and can't drop it.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is an open transaction with a read lock on the table.  This blocks the DROP which is waiting on the release on table.  You need to find this read lock on close the session (by talking to the owner doing another terminate backend).

You can find all the locks on the table with a query like this:

```
select * from pg_locks where relation = (select oid from pg_class where relname = 'the_table');
```

Comment: I have no output from your query. Something get lock yes most likely

Comment: Do you have superuser rights?  I'll ponder what else could be causing a DROP to hang.